# Can a SharePoint 2010 workflow check out a document to a specific user?

Tags: 2010, workflow, check-out, impersonation

Is it possible, within a SharePoint 2010 workflow, to check out the current item to a specific user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the below form post on Microsoft, this can not be done.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58684789-c97c-4c0d-9aca-9bf0285a818b/workflow-checkout-to-user?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious